# Codeplex-like TFS configuration

Tags: configuration, tfs, dns

Hey guys. I'm trying to configure TFS2010 on a home server. I want to use TFS in such way: 
1)Some contributers are working in a small home office working with the same domain name as a server on which TFS is installed.
2)Other contributers are working remote. And contribute code through the web, accessing the server through router.

I think it is codeplex-like config. But i could not find a solution. Please help.

Comment: *Do you want to help support the Visual Studio ALM community on Stack Exchange? http://bit.ly/caQ9ds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work remote, but you cannot do Version Control from TWA (web access). To be able to do Version Control, you must use Team Explorer and open up your TFS by routing port 8080 to your own home server.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx for more information

Comment: @knifewounded that is easily set-up using the link @Ewald Hofman provided above.

Comment: @knifewounded it is worth point out that you may need to setup a port forward for the correct port from your router to your home server.

Comment: thx i've already found information about port forwarding, one more question will this work without domain policy? e.g there are different domain names in one lan

Comment: Yes.  You can set up local users on the TFS machine, which will prompt them for credentials when they try to connect.

Comment: Every user can store the remote TFS credentials in the Credential Cache. See http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/05/21/Automatically-connect-to-TFS-under-another-user-account.aspx